# What is the the formula for pressure of fluid, filled in hollow sphere at Zero Gravity?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, space

Consider a non motile(having no velocity) hollow metal sphere standing in outer  space in absence of gravitational field fulfilled with fluid (liquid or gas), what be the pressure exerted on inner surface of sphere. Neglect gravity of sphere, surface tension and any external force.
Then how can we calculated pressure inside sphere, and what will be the formula to calculate pressure?

Comment: This is really a thermodynamics question.  It depends on the amount of gas in the sphere (number of moles n), the sphere volume, and the temperature.  As a first approximation, the ideal gas law is PV=nRT.  For other materials, the pressure is determined by the equation of state (EOS) for that material.

Comment: While filling the sphere you must exert some pressure on it to make it flow into the sphere. So the pressure of fluid will be the pressure at which it is filled. This is an operational definition, the fundamental one being that pointed out by Chester Miller.

Comment: I can calculate it by the formula of ideal gas equation (PV=nRT).